# What are common control strategies for dosing pumps?

Tags: measurement, control-system

Dosing pumps means pumps that dose a specific amount with a high accuracy. In many process control scenarios, level gauges or flow meters are used (with low accuracy, at least in some cases), what other strategies are widely used?
Sources/Examples would be appreciated.

**Edit** 2012-07-19
My questions are, what measurements are taken (if any), how are the diverse inexactitudes accounted for and where along the drive train do you control the pump (FI-controlled motors vs. just turning off after Volume X is pumped, for example)
I can imagine a lot of ways to do this, but I don't know why one way may be superior to another in a given situation.

Comment: Try search for chemical dosing pump. They are widely used by PCB manufacturers.

Comment: related article: [Motion Control Requirements for Medical Instruments](http://www.techbriefs.com/component/content/article/23-ntb/features/feature-articles/9621), Tech Briefs (free-of-charge industry rag), 2011

Answer (score 1):

There are thousands of ways and products to mix fluids and gases , titration pumps, pulse pumps digitally controlled, radial pumps, bubble control pumps for gases &  medical, consumer, industrial, military, aerospace for many industries.

Basic designs include;

1. Rotary pumps => Consumer: Aquarium version shown here[image]
2. Reciprocating Style Metering Pumps =>

   - displacing a fixed volume through the reciprocating motion using;
   - a piston, a diaphragm, or a bellows
3. Liquid Diaphragm Pumps ( like those used in fuel pumps )
4. Diaphragm Liquid Metering Pumps ( discontinuous pulsed operation, including those with magnetic drive)
5. Electronically Controlled Diaphragm Metering Pump ( more precise with flow sensing )
6. Pulsed syringe mixer with rate and cc. pulse control

Can you articulate your requirements in more detail? 
Got Specs?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe many medical infusion pumps use any volume or flow feedback.  They are built to very tight specs, have very precise instructions for use, and are calibrated.  I know this to be the case for the one or two  I've had opened up in my hands.  I don't know about syringe pumps but I wouldn't be surprised if they had position encoder feedback.